# Modify accessoryCircularCapacity gauge background and thickness in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, gauge

How can I modify the following gauge's background? So in this case, the slightly transparent green.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Gauge(value: 42, in: 0 ... 100) {
            Text("")
        }
        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
        .tint(.green)
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to set it to `.clear` in order to be able to stack multiple gauges. I was also not able to find a modifier to change the thickness of the gauge.